# Having trouble fixing Called to unidentified method?

Tags: php, laravel

For some reason my samplePartNumber code is no longer working together and I keep getting errors on it.  The current one isFatal error: Call to undefined method Web\Forms\SamplePartNumberForm::validate() in /Users/bradley/code/website/app/tests/unit/Web/Forms/SamplePartNumberFormTest.php on line 28

I have gone through the code like a hundred times and would appreciate the fresh set of eyes.

Here is the tests:

```
<?php
use \Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
class SamplePartNumberFormTest extends TestCase
{

/**
 * Setup method
 */
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->form = $this->app->make('Mle\Web\Forms\SamplePartNumberForm');
}


/**
 * @test
 */
public function returns_true_with_valid_input()
{
    $input = [
        'part_number' => 'ASD-5',
        'quantity' => '3',
        'annual_usage' => '22000',
    ];

    $result = $this->form->validate($input);
    $this->assertTrue($result);
}


/**
 * @test
 *
 * @expectedException \Mle\Web\Forms\FormValidationException
 */
public function throws_exception_with_invalid_input()
{
    $input = [];
    $result = $this->form->validate($input);
}
}
```

Here is the form:

```
<?php
namespace Web\Forms;
use Forms\ValidatableFormInterface;
use Forms\FormValidator;
class SamplePartNumberForm implements ValidatableFormInterface
{

use FormValidator;

/**
 * Rules for validation
 * @var array
 */
protected $rules = ['part_number' => 'required', 'quantity' => 'required',    
'annual_usage'=> 'required'];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = $this->form->validate($input);
```

You are receiving an error at this line because your **\Web\Forms\SamplePartNumberForm** class represented here by **$this->form** instance is missing the method **validate()**. You need to implement it in the **validate(array $input_structure)**

Second you have an illegal import use inside the class. This needs to be in the global scope of the file aka outside the **class{}** body; I recommend it after the namespace declaration.

```
class SamplePartNumberForm implements ValidatableFormInterface
{
  use FormValidator;
}
```

Third, if you have any methods inside the **ValidatableFormInterface** you also need to implement them in the SamplePartNumberForm class with a public visibility.

Comment: So the problem is on the form not the test.

Comment: Yes. The form class doesn't have the validate() method. If you could show me the SamplePartNumberForm source code, I could give a more accurate answer in how to fix this.